# Redux: How to organize many selectors?

Tags: javascript, redux

As the application gets bigger the selectors increases. My question is: **How to organize large amount of selectors?**

It is good to define selectors near the root reducer in order to encapsulate the state shape. But putting all the selectors in one file with the root reducer does not seem to be a maintainable approach.

I have asked a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265572/redux-another-implementation-for-selector-pattern) which suggested an idea for structuring selectors to solve other problems but it doesn't fully solve the problem of having many selectors.

Comment: I think it's overkill/verbose to use selectors on something that's just getting a value rather than doing computation (just my opinion, my main use for selectors is separating out complexity and using caching on results), I only have simple ones in the selector file for building up more complex computational selectors. I have my selectors in a selectors folder named after the reducer.

Comment: putting selectors in another file does not serve the purpose of encapsulating the state shape and avoiding changing one and forgetting to change the other. The very problem is in keeping selectors with reducers while repeating private selectors as public selectors.